# MongoDB c# driver - ForEachAsync vs ToListAsync

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using MongoDB c# driver to achieve the following: for all records satisfying certain criteria, set one of the records date fields to the value of another date field.
I was hoping to use `UpdateAllAsync` for that but seems there is no convenient way to do it.
So now I wonder about using `ForEachAsync` vs using `ToListAsync`:

```
await this.repository.Find(filter).ForEachAsync(async record =>
{
    await this.repository.UpdateOneAsync(
        Builders<Records>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, record.Id),
        Builders<Records>.Update.Set(x => x.Date1, record.Date2));
});
```

vs

```
var records = await this.repository.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
foreach (var record in records)
{
    await this.repository.UpdateOneAsync(
        Builders<Records>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, record.Id),
        Builders<Records>.Update.Set(x => x.Date1, record.Date2));  
}
```

Is the first approach safe? Which approach is better in this case?

Answer (score 2):

#### Differences

`ToListAsync()` Will bring all the data in memory and then iterate on them. If we are talking about a huge number of rows, this could lead to too much memory being used for a long period of time.

`ForEachAsync()` On the other hand, will read one row at a time in an asynchronous maner and will not  bring everything to the memory. Under the hood, the Async Enumerator will just use the `ReadAsync()` over the result set to return the next item.

Both will run asynchronously, which means that they will not block the main thread.

#### Why `ToListAsync`

There is a limitation to the `ForEachAsync` extention.

Check the Signature: `ForEachAsync(IQueryable, Action<Object>)` It only take an `Action` delegate, which means that if you need any return value from your operation, you can't use it.

Nice workaround for the limitations of `ForEachAsync` here: [Unexpected behaviour with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ForEachAsync<T>()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920636/unexpected-behaviour-with-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-entityframeworkqueryable)

Comment: The `ForEachAsync` only accepting an `Action<Object>` instead of a `Func<Task, Object>` also means that it shouldn’t be used with asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: Cheers for pointing it out! I added a workaround for bypassing these problems based on another answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @athanasios-kataras.
In my example, I used an alternative signature:  
`public static Task ForEachAsync<TDocument>(this IAsyncCursor<TDocument> source, Func<TDocument, Task> processor, CancellationToken cancellationToken = null )`,
and according to the specification, it returns a Task that completes when all the documents have been processed.
(see [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IAsyncCursorExtensions_ForEachAsync__1_2.htm)). Do you know how this compares to `ToListAsync`?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, ForEachAsync will bring items in-memory one by one and it does the processing in memory? Or it does do the processing in mongo and then return our elements, similar to Projection?